# Django Model form is not shown

Tags: django, forms

I am probably missing something very simple, because my model form is not shown at the template. The code is very simple:

models.py:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/post_images')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class StoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Story
```

views.py:

```
from sfv.forms import StoryForm

@login_required(redirect_field_name=None)
def restricted(request):
    user = request.user
    form = StoryForm()
    #graph = get_persistent_graph(request)
    return render(request, "restricted.html", {user : 'user', form : 'form',})
```

template:

```
<form method = 'POST' action = ''>
<table>
{{ form }}
<table>
</form>
```

I have also tried `form.as_p`, that didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `render` method from

```
return render(request, "restricted.html", {user : 'user', form : 'form',})
```

to

```
return render(request, "restricted.html", { 'user' : user, 'form' : form})
```

The `key` and `value` in the context dictionary were interchanged. Hence the issue.

Comment: Yup, this helped, thank you. I am wondering why I did not get any errors. A couple of hours wasted :/